# Error when compiling with Windows DDK

Tags: windows, wdk

Forgive me for being a complete newbie with Windows DDK.

I have create a simple file named `test.cpp`:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define BAD_ADDRESS 0xBAADF00D

int __cdecl main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    char* p =(char*)BAD_ADDRESS;
    *p='A';
    return 0;
}
```

In the same directory I created a `sources` file like this:

```
TARGETNAME=test
TARGETTYPE=PROGRAM
TARGETPATH=obj

TARGETLIBS=$(SDK_LIB_PATH)\kernel32.lib 

SOURCES= test.cpp
```

And a `makefile` like this:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!!!  Edit .\sources. if you want to add a new source
# file to this component.  This file merely indirects to the real make file
# that is shared by all the components of Windows
#
!INCLUDE $(NTMAKEENV)\makefile.def
```

After launching the Windows XP Free Build Environment I browse to the directory with the three files (test.cpp, makefile and sources) and run the following command:

```
F:\temp\debug\dir1>build -cZg
```

Which outputs:

```
BUILD: Adding /Y to COPYCMD so xcopy ops won't hang.
BUILD: Using 2 child processes
BUILD: Object root set to: ==> objfre_wxp_x86
BUILD: Compile and Link for i386
BUILD: Examining f:\temp\debug\dir1 directory for files to compile.
BUILD: Compiling (NoSync) f:\temp\debug\dir1 directory
1>Compiling - test.cpp for i386
BUILD: Compiling  f:\temp\debug\dir1 directory
BUILD: Linking f:\temp\debug\dir1 directory
1>Linking Executable - objfre_wxp_x86\i386\test.exe for i386
BUILD: Done

    2 files compiled
    1 executable built
```

The problem is that when I run the created executable `test.exe` it says:

```
F:\temp\debug\dir1\objfre_wxp_x86\i386>test
The F:\temp\debug\dir1\objfre_wxp_x86\i386\test.exe application cannot be run in Win32 mode.
```

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rob Walker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226790/error-when-compiling-with-windows-ddk#226952) explains the why but [Kernel Mustard](http://blogs.msmvps.com/kernelmustard/2005/11/04/building-win32-apps-with-build-exe-and-the-ddk/) explains the how.

Comment: This one got close enough to allow be to do the job. Setting it to accepted even tough it required some tuning.

Comment: Kernel Mustard link is now dead :(

Answer (score 3):

You have compiled a 'native application' rather than a win32 one.  The TARGET_TYPE definition controls this.

See '[Inside Native Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447.aspx)' for a discussion of using the DDK to generate a native application.